# Can you stop an <img> tag from loading its image using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

Is there any way to stop an `<img>` tag loading its image by just using CSS?  I would like to avoid using JavaScript.

This doesn't seem to work (Firebug still shows the images loading):

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: It may be helpful to give a bit more of background? Why are you able to modify the css but not the html? Do you want to display the images at a later time?

Comment: Why avoid JavaScript, its just as supported as css ?

Comment: I am somewhat able to modify the html (it's a drupal view listing), but I guess i'll just settle on using two views so i can style the first article to use a "large" image and the rest the small one, either that or Paul D's solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No — CSS only tells browsers what content should look like, it doesn’t specify loading behaviour.

The best you could do that involves CSS is to remove the `<img>` tag from your HTML, and replace it with an element that shows an image via CSS’s `background-image` property. Then the image is controlled more in the CSS than the HTML.

I still don’t think you can guarantee when the image will be downloaded though — I seem to remember early versions of Safari would download images referenced in a stylesheet even if they weren’t used on the current page? Using JavaScript (to create the `<img>` tag when you want the image loaded) is probably the most reliable way of controlling the timing of images getting loaded.

However, have a look at the page linked to from [@Stackle’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24157174/20578) to see the loading behaviour of browsers in April 2012 with different bits of CSS that hide elements with background images.

Comment: That's pretty much it I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the right answer - the [W3C is working on something](http://usecases.responsiveimages.org/) but it could be a while before it's standardized. For now, JS is your only option.

Comment: JS is not the only solution: some excellent examples of using background images can be found at: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/. (just realised that the answer from Stackle covers this :) ) Not perfect for all situations, but can be used in a number of circumstances

Comment: @HamishRouse: sure, although I wouldn’t like to rely on the results from that page. I’m not sure the browsers have decided what the best behaviour is in all circumstances yet, so I wouldn’t be surprised if some or all of them changed their behaviour in future. If you’ve got any sources from browser developers talking about this stuff, grand, but if you actually want to control when images load, I think you’re better off amending your HTML or JavaScript to explicitly do that, rather than relying on some CSS which happens to currently produce the result you want.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question but today we can do it by using css only.

The answer is Yes, but not support on some browser.
See this http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: Refrain from using off-site links. The linked content may change or become invalid. Better try to move corresponding content here and add the link as ongoing informative link.

Comment: The answer *to the actual question asked* (i.e. “is there any way to stop an `<img>` tag loading its image by just using CSS ?”) is still no.

Comment: superb document with exact examples - test cases - results. but @Sebastian is true..

Answer (score 1):

You can [PRELOAD images using CSS only](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/07/22/css-throwdown-preload-images-without-javascript/), but not actually delay the loading of images using CSS only.

This can, however, be done easily using something like [jQuery Lazy Loader](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), which is MUCH easier than trying to do it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as you can see lazy loader doesn't quite work anymore, plus I didn't want to "preload", I just didn't want to load it at all.

Answer (score -6):

Place this at the end of your style sheet:

```
* img { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score -6):

You then set them all to be

```
    .img{visibility:hidden;}
```

this will prevent them from making an http request but still preserves their size and spacing in the document preventing any redraws.

then when you want to show your hidden images (for instance the ones in view) you add a class to the surrounding html element and in your css tell this to be

```
    .show .img {visibility:visible;}
```

That should do it, Holmes.